# this not working in android recycler view adapter Intent

Tags: java, android, xml, firebase

**`this` not working in android recycler view adapter Intent**

**What I Have To Do:**

*Open Activity Onclick On Card And Show Details In The Activity*

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull myviewholder holder, int position) {
        holder.username.setText(datalist.get(position).getUsername());
        holder.email.setText(datalist.get(position).getEmail());
        holder.aadhar.setText("Aadhar: "+datalist.get(position).getAadhar());
        holder.dob.setText("DOB: "+datalist.get(position).getDob());
        holder.dl.setText("DL: "+datalist.get(position).getDl());
        Picasso.get().load(datalist.get(position).getPhotourl()).into(holder.user_Image);
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent userdetaile = new Intent(this, userdetail.class);
            }
        });
    }
```

**This Line Is Giving Me Error**

```
Intent userdetaile = new Intent(this, userdetail.class);
```

**Mainly `this` is giving me error**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` inside `OnClickListener` refers to instance of Listener, where as `Intent` needs a context, you can pass context which would be in `Adapter` or can get it from `View`, do null checks on context before accessing them

```
Intent userdetaile = Intent(v.getContext(), userdetail.class);
v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: It is giving me error ??
```public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent userdetail = new Intent(View.getContext(), userdetail.class);
                userdetail.putExtra("username", datalist.get(position).getUsername());
                context.startActivity(userdetail);
            }```

Comment: Please Tell Me Something

Comment: Updated view to v

Comment: It Worked Before I Did Some Editing There Please Upvote My Question

Comment: Thanks Rajan Kali I Upvoted Your Answer And Marked It As Answer